# Can't resize root and home partition

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, resize

Hello I have some unallocated space that I got from windows partition. I need to resize root partition by 15GB and home partition by 10GB. I am not able to do it. I red that I have to do it from Live Linux? Will it be possible in my case to resize / and /home partitions? See screenshot down below.

[image: gparted_screenshot]

Comment: You aren't able to resize because both / and /home are mounted, and also, the unallocated space is nowhere near these partitions. IMHO, it would be easier to backup files, and reinstall.

Comment: With a smallish HDD/SSD, I'd first say that your disk is full, and you need to remove/backup some of your data. Then I'd backup your Ubuntu files. move /dev/sda5 left, remove Ubuntu (/dev/sda6/7/8), and then reinstall Ubuntu but without separate / and /home partitions.

Comment: @heynnema Is it safe to move /dev/sda5 left? There can't be any boot failure because there is no /boot or C: drive on it right? How do I detect what is on that partition, because I don't know where it came from. After reinstall what is the best way to organize linux partitions? Is there any way or I just don't have enough space?

Comment: /dev/sda5 is a diagnostic partition... used when Windows won't boot (example) and you request help to test why. Use Windows tools to move it. Don't "organize" the linux partitions like you have with / and /home. Just do a standard Ubuntu install (along side Windows) and you'll gain the space you requested/need. You still need to remove some files, as your HDD/SSD is really full, and that's the real problem.

Comment: You could move /home to unallocated so it increases from 15 GB to 25 GB. Then expand `/` where `/home` used to be and increase it from 15 GB to 30 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the reason you can't resize your partition is that others are in the way and need to be moved first (a partition can only increase size if there is `unallocated space` next to it) and also you need to be running a OS that isn't running/using on any of the drives you want to move. Below there are some instructions for how to resize your partition with plenty of information and tools you will need to get this done with warnings about partitioning:
**Partitioning is dangerous**

From personal experience I've lost a whole partition due to a partitioning failing.
First before partitioning you should always backup important files and folders of the drives you will be moving (`/dev/sda5`,`/dev/sda7`,`/dev/sda8`) (`/dev/sda6` doesn't need to be backed up as it is just virtual RAM.
Best practices is to image these partitions to a separate storage device but that takes up the space of the drive.

By Live Linux it means a Live Disk image of Linux, any live disk image of Linux will work but there is also [GParted Live CD/USB image](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).
After downloading a Live Image you will need to flash it to a spare USB drive (a empty or backed up USB drive as all data will be lost), you can use any USB flashing device but I advise [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) as it will verify the flash.

You need to move `/dev/sda5` to the left all the way (so the `Free space preceding (MiB):` in GParted is `0`) and then you need to move your `/dev/sda6` to the left all the way.
After that you should move `/dev/sda7` all the way to the left and then resize it to the size you require for your root folder and then finally resize `/dev/sda8/` to what size you need in your home folder. I advise that you fill up all the unallocated space so you don't have to partition again as it is dangerous.

Make sure before you partition that you have a spare OS install USB/CD/DVD disk in case the partition fails.
Once you have a backup your files and have a spare OS install ready for the worst case scenario and have made a note of what you need to do then go ahead and repartition your drive.

Hope this helps,
Harry

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I decided to fully reinstall Ubuntu and included the unallocated free space.